# question about the weak* closure of the embedded unit sphere in an infinitely dimensional normed vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\iota : X \to X^{**}$ be the standard isometric embedding of $X$ an infinitely dimensional vector space and $X^{**}$ its bidual space. I know that our embedding is a continous function with respect to the weak topology on $X$ and the weak* topology on $X^{**}$. Can I deduce the following equality:

$\iota(B) = \iota(cl_w(S)) = cl_w^*(\iota(S))$

where in the first step I use the fact that the weak closure of the unit sphere $S\subset X$ is the closed unit ball $B \subset X$ if $X$ is infinitely dimensional and in the second step I use the continuity of $\iota$ as described above.

Is this reasoning right?

Comment: Continuity only gives one inclusion: $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$. So you might need more (openness, maybe).

Comment: Not only is the reasoning not right, the equation is not true. In fact $\iota(S)$ is weak* dense in the unit ball of $X^{**}$.

Comment: thanks @HennoBrandsma ! I was wondering why they only wrote the inclusion in the proof and not equality, silly mistake.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich with reasoning I meant the equation. I do know that $\iota(S)$ is weak* dense in $B^{**} \subset X^{**}$.

Comment: ??? If you know that then why are you asking whether the weak* closure is $\iota(B)$? I don't get this at all...

Comment: I know it as the result of the theorem (" $cl_w^{*}\iota(S)=B^{**}$ ")  I was studying and I was wondering why the equation above does not hold i.e. where my reasoning failed.